# Sum Column based on date in header

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need assistance with a formula to sum data in columns based on a date. My data is below.  I am trying to write a formula or VBA to sum the data for all hours charged by Acme employees after 5/22/15.  I've tried SUMIF and SUMIFS formulas but somewhere I'm missing an important element.

```
NAME        CO  5/15  5/22 5/29 6/5
Marco Polo  Acme    8   5   8   5
Ms. Piggy   Acme    6   6   8   6
Kermit Frog Mejot   8   8   6   8
John Doe    Mejot   4   8   10  10
```

Comment: There is no data attached to the post !

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I added the data

Answer (score 0):

Put the above date in a excel sheet in the table kind of format

and use the formula

=**IF(COUNTIF(A1:F1,I3),SUM(INDEX($A$2:$F$5,0,MATCH(I3,A1:F1,0))))**

WHERE A1:F1 is the header and I3 is a cell where i will give the date i want to match in your case I3 is 5/22.By using the above formula you can get the sum you require.